# Should Builder Pattern be used as a wrapper?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

Trying to evaluate whether or not to replace a cluttered chart helper class with the builder pattern.  In the helper class there are methods like these:

[ChartHelper]

```
public static ChartTitle CreateStandardChartTitle(string titleText){}
public static void SetBarWidths( BarSeriesView bars ){}
public static void SetHorizontalChartHeight( WebChartControl chart, 
    int seriesCount, int margin ){}
public static void SetVerticalChartWidth( WebChartControl chart, 
    int seriesCount, int margin ){}
public static Legend SetStandardLegendProperties(WebChartControl chart){}
```

Obviously, these methods modify existing objects and are just modifying various properties on the WebChartControl.  This works pretty good for most scenarios, but the methods don't always apply to all the possible chart types (bar, line, pie, etc) and there are sometimes different "configurations" of how a chart should look that deviate from these helper methods.  **Rather than try to satisfy these different "configurations" using a helper class, I was wondering about the builder pattern.**

From what I understand the builder pattern is used to construct complex objects.  In my case, I already have the complex object created (the WebChartControl).  So, if I were to use the builder pattern, it would be just wrapping up instead of creating the WebChartControl.

I tossed some code together from what I am envisioning:

Director:

```
public class ChartDirector
{
    private WebChartControl chart;
    public ChartDirector(WebChartControl chart)
    {
        this.chart = chart;
    }
    private StandardChartBuilder standardBuilder;
    public void Construct(StandardChartBuilder standardBuilder)
    {
        this.standardBuilder = standardBuilder;
        this.standardBuilder.Chart = this.chart;
        this.standardBuilder.BuildBorderOptions();
        this.standardBuilder.BuildPalette();
        this.standardBuilder.BuildLegend();
        this.standardBuilder.BuildSeriesLabel();
    }
}
```

Concrete Builder:

```
public class BarChartBuilder : StandardChartBuilder
{
    public WebChartControl Chart { get; set; }

    public BarChartBuilder()
        : base(ChartType.Bar)
    {

    }
    public override void BuildBorderOptions()
    {
        Chart.BorderOptions.Visible = false;
    }
   ...
}
```

Abstract builder, allows for different configurations...:

```
public abstract class StandardChartBuilder
{
    public WebChartControl Chart { get; set; }

    public StandardChartBuilder(ChartType chartType){}

    public abstract void BuildSeriesLabel();       
    public abstract void BuildBorderOptions();
    public abstract void BuildPalette();
    public abstract Legend BuildLegend();
}
```

As you can see from the code above, ChartDirector is not creating a *new* object, it is just modifying properties of an existing object that is being wrapped up.

**So, my question still stands, should I replace the ChartHelper class with the builder pattern, even though this is not a pure implementation of the builder pattern?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion, if you are sure that any chart in your app can be manipulated (call it configured, if you wish) with this or other but *unique* set of methods or properties you can switch to Builder pattern.  The thing is it's not very clear if your phrase

> Rather than try to satisfy these different configurations

can fit in domain of methods and properties provided by single abstract `StandardChartBuilder` class. If, yes, Builder is definitely an option.

Comment: Configurations in this context just mean different implementations of the abstract class.  For example, if in one case, instead of making the Border invisible, there may be a time it needs to be visible.  I suppose if one abstract class isn't enough, abstract factory pattern could be used.  The idea however is to limit the number of "standards" for a given chart type (bar, pie).  The helper class can do it as well, by using switch, if, etc in each helper method, but that seems messy.

Comment: @subt13: that was actually my doubt, if this class is enough (as can not be figure out just from the question). At this point, Builder is your choice.